# D3.js - How to call nested values of strings in a bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I want to draw a bar chart with D3.js with a csv that contains the folllowing values:

```
**name**
apple
apple
apple
banana
```

I've nested my data like that:

```
var fruits = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return v.length })
  .entries(data);
```

With console.log(fruits), I can see the following structure:

```
(2) [Object, Object]
    0:Object
      key:"apple"
      values:3
```

Which is what I want: how many rows contains each fruit name? However, when I try to build my bar chart, I've got an error:

```
Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN".
```

I've tried different things, but nothing works.

```
var svg = d3.select("#barChart")
        .attr("viewBox", [
           0,
           0,
           width2,
           height2
         ].join(" "));

var g = svg.append("g");

widthScale.domain([ 0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.values;
  }) ]);

heightScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.values; } ));  

var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(fruits)
        .enter()
        .append("rect");

  rects.attr("x", padding[3])
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return heightScale(d.key);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d,i) {   
      return widthScale(+d.values);
    })
    .attr("height", heightScale.rangeBand())
```

Nor

```
.attr("width", function(d,i) { 
  return widthScale(+fruits[i].values);
})
.attr("height", heightScale.rangeBand())
```

How can I access to the nested values in order to create my bar chart?

Comment: Both your snippets do work. You probably have other problem somewhere else, we need to see more code. Please, copy/paste your scales and the enter selection.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I've put more code! Thank you.

Comment: Is that all your code? Where is height?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado         .attr("height", heightScale.rangeBand())

Comment: I just deleted my answer, which used v4... I couldn't tell that you're using v3, and the edit with `rangeBand()`, which was a clue, was posted after I wrote my answer... I have no time to change it to v3 now, hope someone else helps you.

Comment: Absolutely! I've adapted my code for the v4 version, and it works perfectly. Thank you very much for your kind help, I was stuck on this problem for hours.